# Ansible / Limit tag to group and localhost

Tags: ansible

Im trying to run my playbook on all machines with tag: `mytag` with additional param `my-zone` and on the localhost which is executed the playbook. I tried this:

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -i myinventory -e --limit localhost,tag_mytag:&my-zone
```

but it gives me the next error:

```
ERROR! Specified --limit does not match any hosts
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as below::

```
   ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -i myinventory --limit localhost --tag mytag -e var=x
```

assuming here that, i am limiting my playbook to run only to localhost(--limit).
with tag "mytag" (--tag ) and passing an extra variable ( -e ) as "var=x"